# excell in C# - got problem with 2 sheet

Tags: c#, excel

i use this code for making excell from dataset:

```
SQL = "select Bar,Store,Serial from Counter";
            dsView = new DataSet();
            adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, Conn);
            adp.Fill(dsView, "Counter");
            adp.Dispose();
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xla = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        xla.Visible = false  ; 
        Workbook wb = xla.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
        Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)xla.ActiveSheet;
        int i = 1;
        foreach (DataRow comp in dsView.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            ws.Cells[i, 1] = comp[0].ToString();
            ws.Cells[i, 2] = comp[1].ToString();
            ws.Cells[i, 3] = comp[2].ToString();
            i++;
        }
```

and i have 2 problem

how to open new sheet  and how to close this process

(i see that the Excell allwais runs on background)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **How to open new sheet?**

You may add a new sheet by using the `Workbook.Worksheets.Add` method.

```
var newWorksheet = 
    (Worksheet)xla.Worksheets.Add(Type.Missing
                                , Type.Missing
                                , Type.Missing
                                , Type.Missing);
```

> **How to close this process?**

You have to close the workbooks and dispose of the application instance.

```
SQL = "select Bar,Store,Serial from Counter";
dsView = new DataSet();
using (adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, Conn)) 
    using (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xla = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()) {
        adp.Fill(dsView, "Counter");

        xla.Visible = false  ; 

        try {
            Workbook wb = xla.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
            Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)xla.ActiveSheet;

            int i = 1;

            foreach (DataRow comp in dsView.Tables[0].Rows) {
                ws.Cells[i, 1] = comp[0].ToString();
                ws.Cells[i, 2] = comp[1].ToString();
                ws.Cells[i, 3] = comp[2].ToString();
                i++;
            }
        } finally {
            // Notice that the two following lines are totally optional as the use of 
            // using blocks assure that the used resource will necessarily be disposed
            // when getting out of the using blocks scope.
            adp.Dispose();
            xla.Dispose();
        }
}
```

Here a few links for getting acquainted to working with the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` COM assembly.

1. [How to: Add New Worksheets to Workbooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fczc37s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx);
2. [Working with Worksheets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157882.aspx);
3. [Working with Workbooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386180.aspx);
4. [Working with Ranges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386091.aspx);
5. [Working with Cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157868.aspx).